# How to set a text with whitespaces on xtext

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to set somethin like:

Question:
'My question: How old are you'  answer=Answer
;

Answer: value=ID;

But its not possible to se a quuoted text with whitespaces, there is any way to do it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Would it be possible to rephrase your question? I cannot understand what are you intending to do

Comment: `ID` is an ID. You are most likely looking for `STRING` instead?

Comment: maybe you can do a `STUFF: (ID | INT | STRING)+`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING on your question

```
Model:
  questions+=Question*
;

Question:
  'My question: ' declare=STRING answer=Answer
;

Answer:
  name=STRING
;
```

Here you'll always add "My question " following your declared question and answer. The DSL could then look like this:

```
My question: "How old are you?" "I'm old enough"
```